# Window is not responding to XMoveResizeWindow request

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, x11

I have one window manager code, which can do window Move, window resize. But when I try to do both at the same time with XMoveResizeWindow, it does not working, and no error log also coming.

My code is given below

```
void WindowMgrLib::MoveResizeWindow(Window window, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XSetErrorHandler(catch_error);
    XMoveResizeWindow(display, window, x, y, width, height);
    printf("x = %d, y= %d, width = %d, height=%d\n", x, y, width, height);
    XFlush(display);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}

void WindowMgrLib::MoveWindow(Window window, int x, int y)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XSetErrorHandler(catch_error);
    XMoveWindow(display, window, x, y);
    XFlush(display);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}

void WindowMgrLib::ResizeWindow(Window window, int w, int h)
{
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XSetErrorHandler(catch_error);
    XResizeWindow(display, window, w, h);
    XFlush(display);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

Here `WindowMgrLib::MoveWindow` and `WindowMgrLib::ResizeWindow` are working fine.
Can somebody tell me what is wrong with `WindowMgrLib::MoveResizeWindow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**XCloseDisplay**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xclosedisplay)

> The XCloseDisplay function closes the connection to the X server for the display specified in the Display structure and **destroys all windows, resource IDs (Window, Font, Pixmap, Colormap, Cursor, and GContext), or other resources that the client has created on this display**, unless the close-down mode of the resource has been changed (see XSetCloseDownMode). Therefore, these windows, resource IDs, and other resources **should never be referenced again** or an error will be generated. Before exiting, you should call XCloseDisplay explicitly so that any pending errors are reported as XCloseDisplay performs a final XSync operation.

**Therefore**:

- open the display once
- do your stuff (creating windows, receive/process events, etc)
- when finished (last window closed): close the display (once)